# Fatal Error when implementing a Keras Model converted to a CoreML model in an iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, keras, coreml, coremltools

I'm making an iOS app that uses a Deep Learning Model developed in Keras and converted to a CoreML model. I was using the Resnet50 CoreML Model downloaded from Apple's website and the app was working flawlessly, but when I implemented the model I developed an error occurred when I chose an image from the photo library or took a picture with the camera within the app. This is the code associated with the CoreML Model and the error I'm getting: [image: Code associated with the CoreML Model] This is the code used to convert the Keras Model into a CoreML model:

```
output_labels = ['0', '1']

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.keras.convert('Costume.h5', input_names=['image'],
                                                class_labels=output_labels, image_input_names='image',
                                                output_names=['output'])

print(coreml_model)  # Check that input type is imageType

# Metadata for XCode
coreml_model.author = 'Author'
coreml_model.short_description = 'Some Description'
coreml_model.input_description['image'] = 'Takes as input an image'
coreml_model.output_description['output'] = 'Prediction of image'

coreml_model.save('Costume.mlmodel')
```

I have no idea how to fix this error, thanks in advance!
This is my Keras Model:

```
model = Sequential()

# Hidden Layer 1
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Hidden Layer 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Hidden Layer 3
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Hidden Layer 4
model.add(Conv2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(256, 3, 3, border_mode='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.0001),
          metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `request.results`? All you've shown with this error message is that it is not an array of `VNVClassificationObservation` objects, but that doesn't tell us what it *is*. Also, is there an error message in the debug output pane?

Comment: `request.results` should be an array of `VNClassificationObservation`, but I don't what type I'm getting on that error. This is the error message in the debug output pane: "Message from debugger: failed to send the k packet". @MatthijsHollemans

Comment: Actually, that debug message appears when I stop the application so that's not associated with the error. The only thing displayed before that is the fatal error mentioned in the post. @MatthijsHollemans

Comment: I wasn't asking about what `request.results` should be, but about what it is. ;-) Add a `print(request.results)` before the guard statement and see what it prints out.

Comment: I added the `print(request.results` using both the Resnet50 and the Costume model. With the Resnet50 model it prints out many classifications ranking them from best confidence to worse confidence after choosing a picture, such as: _[<VNClassificationObservation: 0x60000027b0c0> 8AD478FE-3A1B-416F-96BB-FE886CD107DF requestRevision=1 confidence=0.533675 "dam, dike, dyke"_ and it keeps going with different classifications and with the Costume model it prints out _nil_, which is probably what's causing the error. Any idea why that may happen? Thanks! @MatthijsHollemans

Comment: OK that means Core ML ran into an error. What does `print(error)` write to the debug pane?

Comment: I added `print(error)` right before the guard statement and this is the output on the debug pane: _Optional(Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=3 "The VNCoreMLTransform request failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The VNCoreMLTransform request failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000074cd20 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "The size of the output layer 'output' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The size of the output layer 'output' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier.}}})_. @Mat

Comment: There is your answer: the neural network has more (or fewer) output neurons than there are class names in the model. You can fix this by editing the mlmodel file (using a Python script) and giving it the correct number of class labels. But it's easier to fix this in the conversion script (i.e. change the `output_labels` variable).

Comment: I added my Keras Model in the post for reference because I only have two classes in my network, one of cats and one of dogs. Shouldn't the `output_labels=['0', '1']` if that's the case? I also tried setting `class_labels=['cat', 'dog']` and I still got an error. Thanks for your help! @MatthijsHollemans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem so I'm posting it in case anyone has the same problem in the future. You need to change the following:

```
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

and also remember to change the loss from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy`.